# VBA Multiple variables join together into single variable that can be called to run as a function

Tags: excel, vba, string, function

I am attempting to modify the following function to have variable strings that join together to run the changed final function. I know this isn't right, but I have been googling for a couple of days now and tried a few different methods to no avail. I'm sure I've been googling the wrong information to find the right way to do this, any help would be greatly appreciated! Please note the comment section at the bottom is what I am trying to achieve in the final function.

Update Reason I'm asking:
There are multiple pages(about 10) that I want multiple photos(around 173) to load for and figured it would be a good way to condense the code. Do you know a way to work around this without having to have the 1000 lines of code?

```
Option Explicit

Dim Form As String
Dim Form1 As String
Dim Form2 As String
Dim Form3 As Object

Sub YouthLoadGraphics()
    Form = "Youth"
    Form1 = ".Picture = LoadPicture("
    Form2 = ")"
    Form3 = Form + Form1 + ("C:\temp\forms\Leaving-Youth-Readiness-Assessment-Pens_1.bmp") + Form2
    

    Run Form3
   
    
    
   ' Youth.Picture = LoadPicture("C:\temp\forms\Leaving-Youth-Readiness-Assessment-Pens_1.bmp")
   ' Youth.PictureSizeMode = (3)
End Sub
```

Comment: Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: You cannot execute strings as random pieces of VBA using an approach like this - it's just not supported.   Would help to explain why you want to take that approach.

Comment: There are multiple pages(about 10) that I want multiple photos(around 173) to load for and figured it would be a good way to condense the code. Do you know a way to work around this without having to have the 1000 lines of code?

Comment: How are the images named, is there a pattern ? is there any match between the name of.the control and the name of the bmp file.

Comment: Controls on forms can be accessed by name using the form's `Controls` collection - so `Me.Controls("Youth").Picture = LoadPicture("C:\temp\forms\Leaving-Youth-Readiness-Assessment-Pens_1.bmp")`  in the userform code module should work.  You could store the control names and the associated image paths on a worksheet and use that data to load the images.